# How to create a Spinner that displays an unlisted item in Android dropdown?

Tags: android, datepicker, spinner, google-now

In Google Now's 'reminder' feature, you can set a date after being prompted with a view of a calendar and selecting a date. I noticed that once a date is selected, however, the displayed text of the Spinner is the date selected, however the item is not found in the dropdown list. I would like to to do essentially the same thing for my code.

[image: Reminder's Spinner abilities]

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `SpinnerAdapter` and override `Adapter.getView` for the default "Thursday, April 24" view and `SpinnerAdapter.getDropDownView` for the drop-down list. To bind the data to your `Spinner`, call `Spinner.setAdapter`.

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data
        // set.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the
        // data set
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get a View that displays in the drop down popup the data
        // at the specified position in the data set
        return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

}
```

---

```
final Spinner spinner = ...;
spinner.setAdapter(new YourAdapter());
```

Comment: How do I assign the view "for the default "Thursday, April 24" view?"

Comment: @AlleyOOP It's the `View` you return in `Adapter.getView`.

Comment: what would such a view look like? how does that work? Nothing I can find online explains this in detail

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend an Adapter subclass and then override the getView() method.

```
public class NavigationSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

public NavigationSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView view = (TextView) super
            .getView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.setText("Thursday, April 24");
    return view;
}
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
itemList.add("Today");
itemList.add("Tomorrow");
itemList.add("Set Date...");
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new NavigationSpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, android.R.id.text1, itemList);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(arrayAdapter, this);
```